# JQuery: multiple get() requests to same PHP page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, get

I have a doubt about one method in JavaScript+JQuery to call GET requests.

My code is something like this:

```
function LoadProducts(){
    $.get('php/get.php',{id:100},function(){
        //...
    });
}
function LoadUser(){
    $.get('php/get.php',{id:101},function(){
        //...
    });
}
function LoadThis(){
    $.get('php/get.php',{id:100},function(){
        //...
    });
}
function LoadThat(){
    $.get('php/get.php',{id:100},function(){
        //...
    });
}

//...... And so on, and so on
```

---

**Problem**

I want to make a short version of `$.get()` function because there are around 50 more functions and I don't want to write `'php/get.php'` each time (when the name of this file will be different, I will need to change it 50 times too...)

So, I wrote this code:

```
function GetIt(mode,options,func)           {
    var req = '';
    switch(mode)
    {
        case 0:
            req = 'php/get.php';
        break;
        case 1:

        break;
    }
    $.get(req,options,function(result){func(result);});
}
```

And I'm using it like this:

```
GetIt(0,{page:25},function(result){
    // do stuff
});
```

It is better to put zero (as mode to `GetIt()`) 50 times instead of `'php/get.php'` 50 times.

---

**QUESTION**

Is it a good way? Which is the best choise to optimize code and keep functionality of `$.get()` without having to write the same code multiple times?

Comment: Creating an abstraction for your requests is a good idea yes, but I don't understand the purpose of your `mode` parameter. If it's not `0` you will do a request to `''`, is this intentional?

Comment: @MikaelLennholm mode is for case when will be needed to do a request to other pages, for example `'php/get_config.php'` or something like this. Currently, I only have 1 page, but in future is possible to have more. It's not very important..

Comment: Well, in that case, I would create separate abstraction functions for those other pages, e.g. `function GetIt(options, callback)` for `'php/get.php'` and `function GetConfig(options, callback)` for `'php/get_config.php'`

Comment: `function(result){func(result);}` <-- this line is wrong, can be successfully replaced by `func` as I discovered now. Then on the end of `GetIt()` final line will be like this: `$.get(req,options,func);`. Short and simple :)

Comment: @MikaelLennholm Yes, probably it's good to do too. I'm thinking now that I can replace that `Switch()` to an `array`. like this `var arr =
 ['php/get.php','php/get_config.php']` and then call it like `arr[mode]`. Even shorter now.. Instead of 11 lines GetIt() only has 2 lines now. much more readable